# В чем разница между параметром и аргументом?

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, объясните САМЫМ ДОСТУПНЫМ, легким способом. И, пожалуйста, не так, что a,b - это параметры, а 4,5 - это агрументы. Ведь параметры не всегда имеют строковый тип данных, а аргументы не всегда числовой. Я новичок, поэтому прошу объяснение полегче...

Comment: Параметры — это переменные, аргументы — значения этих переменных

Comment: @andreymal Настолько простое объяснение, а в инете пишут целые повести...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень давно мне помог вот это книга понять разницу между параметром и аргументом.

Книга **Изучаем программирование на JavaScript** стр. 154:

Не уверена, что понимаю разницу между параметром и аргументом:это случайно не одно и тоже?

**Нет, это разные понятие.**

При определении функции вы можете *определить* ее с использованием одного или более *параметров*.

```
//Здесь мы определяем три параметра degrees, mode и duration

function cook(degrees, mode,duration){
  //здесь будет ваш код
}
```

При вызове функции вы вызываете ее с использованием аргументов

```
cook(425.0, "bake",45);
//это аргументы.Здесь имеются три аргумента:число с плавающей точкой,
//строковое значение и целое число
cook(325.0, "broil",10);
```

Таким образом, свои параметры вы будете определять только один раз, а вызывать свои функции станете с использованием массы разных аргументов.

Вас удивит, насколько много людей путается в том, где использются параметры, а где аргументы.В некоторых книгах даже встречается неверное толкование, поэтому если вы где-то увидите что утверждается обратное то будете знать, где правда.

**Функции определяют с использованием параметров, а вызывают с использованием аргументом.**

Answer (score 0):

Параметры - это данные, от которых что-либо зависит.
Термин довольно общий. Параметры не обязательно должны быть описаны в коде (параметром может быть, например, номер порта в конфигурационном файле, или аналоговый сигнал принимаемый от датчика).

Аргументы - это (чаще всего) значения, передаваемые в функцию при ее вызове.
Насколько знаю, этот термин пришел в IT прямиком из математики, где аргументом функции называется независимая переменная, от значений которой зависят значения функции - фактически, тот же смысл.

---

> Ведь параметры не всегда имеют строковый тип данных, а аргументы не всегда числовой.

Типы величин/значений никак не влияют на их роль.

Answer (score 0):

Если это вам поможет лучше запомнить, то параметр(ы) характеризуют функцию при её описании